# PHP error_log file delay in reporting errors

Tags: php, apache, error-log

My VPS server has Apache / PHP 8.1 and when a error found in a PHP file it creates **error_log** file.

That is very helpful for me to troubleshoot errors.

But the problem is that the **error_log** file appears in the server after a long time from the time of error triggers (30-40 minutes later).

How can I set the “**error_log**” file to update in real time as soon as an error is found?

I checked the “**php.ini**” file but didn’t see any time setting for the “**error_log**” file.

I read old posts on StackOverflow but no answer was found.

Comment: it usually appears instantly unless there's something specific in the configuration etc, etc. Anyway, this is off-topic question here. You may want to move to i.e. askubuntu.com or so instead